# Converter número do dia da semana em String do dia

Tags: java

Estou precisando converter o número que corresponde ao dia da semana na *String* do dia em *Java*. Ex:

```
0 => Monday
1 => Tuesday
```

Comment: Ou seja, você quer semanas começando na segunda-feira?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pode utilizar o [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) para isso, exemplo:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("1 = " + DayOfWeek.of(1));
        System.out.println("2 = " + DayOfWeek.of(2));
        System.out.println("3 = " + DayOfWeek.of(3));
        System.out.println("4 = " + DayOfWeek.of(4));
        System.out.println("5 = " + DayOfWeek.of(5));
        System.out.println("6 = " + DayOfWeek.of(6));
        System.out.println("7 = " + DayOfWeek.of(7));
    }

}
```

Veja funcionando no [**repl.it**](https://repl.it/KbFi)

Pode ver mais alguns exemplos: [DayOfWeek and Month Enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/enum.html)